# Can i have a video exported from any markup language, after a form is submitted?

Tags: php, html, forms, video, export

I am working on a project where there is a questionnaire and the answers become a typographic video at the end. Is this possible? If yes how should i go about it?

Comment: I am not sure about flash but there isn't any standard way to accomplish this in html5. Til now!

Comment: Hey Thanks for your effort in answering.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with some jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
//here you could add $("form").hide();
$("video").show();
});
```

You need to give us some more information about what your html/css is, this is the best what I can make up on your question. 
The video should be "display:none" in css.
You also could add

```
$("form").hide();
```

To hide your form, and only show the video.
Ill edit my question if you give more information.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your effort in answering, but my question is not hide or show the video. The video gets generated based on the answers for the questionnaire.

Comment: @user2283274 Then PHP is needed, I am in a hurry so you could look there: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp <--- sorry for w3schools, but it is plain and simple with PHP, so simple, that even w3schools is correct about this.